# Why does the first line of a batch file fails to execute?

Tags: batch-file, syntax

I am trying to understand why the first line of my batch file fails to execute. My code is as follows:

```
if exist reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" goto OptionOne
exit
:OptionOne
some code
goto:eof
```

It never goes to the `OptionOne` subroutine. Instead, it just exits.

I do have a solution to this problem written differently (so I don't want examples to make it work) but I want to understand why this one line fails to execute.

- Is the syntax improper? Google says it is correct.
- Poorly designed code? I know this registry key exists so this is not the case.
- Is it something with the return value and its correct syntax, but needs to be further written out on the else statements?

Comment: This is because `reg query....` is a command. `if exist` is for files or folders. Can you describe what you want to achieve by the way? Do you want to check if `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion` exist? A simple solution would be `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" >nul 2>&1` and the next line: `if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (goto :OptionOne)`. Is this the code you have and works?

Comment: The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question.

Comment: Yes I did the if exist %errorlevel% EQU 0 method. Just didn't know/understand about the if exist. Thank you.

Sorry about the tags.

Comment: **if**, not "if exist".

Comment: `IF EXIST` is used to test the existence of a file or folder. It cannot be used to test if a variable exists. That is what `IF DEFINED` is for. Clearly you have not read any of the console help or the help Microsoft has on their website for the `IF` command.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have doesn't work because `if exist` is used **only** to check if folders or files exist. Its syntax is:

```bat
if exist "C:\foldername\" (do something) else (optionally do something else)
```

for folders and:

```bat
if exist "C:\filename" (do something) else (optionally do something else)
```

for files.

My suggested solution (as mentioned in comments) is the following:

```bat
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" >nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (goto :OptionOne) else (echo Registry key not found. & pause>nul & exit /b 1)

:OptionOne
some code
goto :eof
```

which checks if the command returned `errorlevel` ***different* than equal to `1` or bigger** (the registry key exists) or `1` or bigger (it doesn't exist).

Comment: also `reg query … >nul 2>&1 && echo success || echo failed`

Comment: `if %errorlevel% EQU 0` would not work if this command line and the `reg query` command line above are inside a command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)`. The help of command __IF__ output on running `if /?` in a command prompt window explains at top the `IF [NOT] ERRORLEVEL number command` syntax which should be preferred used for evaluating exit code of a command or application. So better would be using `if not errorlevel 1 (goto OptionOne) else (echo ...)`. `IF [NOT] ERROLEVEL` is also executed much faster although time difference is not really noticeable for a user.

Answer (score 0):

REG QUERY only returns 0 for success or 1 for failure.  Note that no results is still a successful query operation and will return 0.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-query

And as commentors noted, IF EXIST is only for files and folders, not for commands.

Answer (score 0):

Just launch `reg query` and check `%errorlevel%`, as you can see here:

```
Prompt>reg query "HKCU\..." (put something which exists)

<some successful answers>
Prompt>echo %errorlevel%
0

Prompt>reg query "blabla"
ERROR: Invalid key name.
Type "REG QUERY /?" for usage.

Prompt>echo %errorlevel%
1
```

You can check `%errorlevel%` in your batch script.